# v-treeview expand collapse implementation

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDEQw.png)

I am using v-treeview in vuejs. i am getting the items dynamically while clicking in nodes children i am showing the different modules.i want to implement collapse and expand logic. if i am clicking on one node the last update node should be collapsed and clicked node should be expand.

```
<div class="card card-side-bar">
          <v-treeview
            :items="modules"
            :open.sync="open"
            open-on-click
            v-model="tree"
            :active.sync="active"
            activatable
            transition
            :items-children="modules.children"
            @update:active="test()"
          >
            <template v-slot:prepend="{ item, active }"></template>
          </v-treeview>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `@update:open` event which emits the array of open items. If you want only one item to be expanded - then you should remove all items from this array except the last and assign this array to the `open` prop of `v-treeview`.